# Entity Framework get entity ID by record

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have a form where user save new estate. In that form he can choose from a combobox a client name that already registered in client table. ID of new estate and client ID that own that estate are saves in estate table. The problem is that I cannot figure out how can I get ID by selected client name in combobox.

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectClientcomboBox.DataSource = AgencyContext.Client.ToList();
        SelectClientcomboBox.DisplayMember = "ClientName";
        SelectClientcomboBox.Invalidate();
    }
    private void SaveEstateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Estate estate = new Estate();
        estate.ClientID =
    }
```

Comment: In combox user select clients name from clients table I need somewhow get ID of this selected client.

Comment: you want to get clientid based on client name form databse ?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Form_Load bind the value member property

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectClientcomboBox.DataSource = AgencyContext.Client.ToList();
    SelectClientcomboBox.DisplayMember = "ClientName";
    SelectClientcomboBox.ValueMember = "ClientID";
    SelectClientcomboBox.Invalidate();
}
```

And when you want to access this ID, you can get the selected value.

```
private void SaveEstateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Estate estate = new Estate();
    estate.ClientID = SelectClientcomboBox.SelectedValue;
}
```